# Android Studio | Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details pero sin error aparente

Tags: android, android-studio

Estoy haciendo un reproductor de musica de un tutorial que encontre en github y lo segui paso a paso sin irme a otros lados a hacer o deshacer y en realidad no me marca ningun error o mensaje del porque estoy mal mas aparte del mensaje al ejectur mi app donde al instalarla en mi telefono entra y se sale rapidamente dejando de responder, no logro percibir la libreria obsoleta o el que parte de codigo esta aparentemente bien pero mal en el fondo:

> Note: C:\Users\HP\AndroidStudioProjects\MusicPlayer\app\src\main\java\com\example\musicplayer\MusicService.java uses or overrides a deprecated API. Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

Aca esta mi codigo para que me puedan proporcionar ayuda:

```
package com.example.musicplayer;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.ContentUris;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Binder;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.os.PowerManager;
import android.util.Log;

public class MusicService extends Service implements
        MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener, MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener,
        MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener {
    //media player
    private MediaPlayer player;
    //song list
    private ArrayList<Song> songs;
    //current position
    private int songPosn;
    //binder
    private final IBinder musicBind = new MusicBinder();
    //title of current song
    private String songTitle="";
    //notification id
    private static final int NOTIFY_ID=1;
    //shuffle flag and random
    private boolean shuffle=false;
    private Random rand;

    public void onCreate(){
        //create the service
        super.onCreate();
        //initialize position
        songPosn=0;
        //random
        rand=new Random();
        //create player
        player = new MediaPlayer();
        //initialize
        initMusicPlayer();
    }

    public void initMusicPlayer(){
        //set player properties
        player.setWakeMode(getApplicationContext(),
                PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK);
        player.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        //set listeners
        player.setOnPreparedListener(this);
        player.setOnCompletionListener(this);
        player.setOnErrorListener(this);
    }

    //pass song list
    public void setList(ArrayList<Song> theSongs){

        songs=theSongs;
    }

    //binder
    public class MusicBinder extends Binder {
        MusicService getService() {

            return MusicService.this;
        }
    }

    //activity will bind to service

    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return musicBind;
    }

    //release resources when unbind

    public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent){
        player.stop();
        player.release();
        return false;
    }

    //play a song
    public void playSong(){
        //play
        player.reset();
        //get song
        Song playSong = songs.get(songPosn);
        //get title
        songTitle=playSong.getTitle();
        //get id
        long currSong = playSong.getID();
        //set uri
        Uri trackUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                currSong);
        //set the data source
        try{
            player.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(), trackUri);
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("MUSIC SERVICE", "Error setting data source", e);
        }
        player.prepareAsync();
    }

    //set the song
    public void setSong(int songIndex){

        songPosn=songIndex;
    }

    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
        //check if playback has reached the end of a track
        if(player.getCurrentPosition()>0){
            mp.reset();
            playNext();
        }
    }

    public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
        Log.v("MUSIC PLAYER", "Playback Error");
        mp.reset();
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
        //start playback
        mp.start();
        //notification
        Intent notIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        notIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendInt = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                notIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(this);

        builder.setContentIntent(pendInt)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.play)
                .setTicker(songTitle)
                .setOngoing(true)
                .setContentTitle("Playing")
                .setContentText(songTitle);
        Notification not = builder.build();
        startForeground(NOTIFY_ID, not);
    }

    //playback methods
    public int getPosn(){

        return player.getCurrentPosition();
    }

    public int getDur(){

        return player.getDuration();
    }

    public boolean isPng(){

        return player.isPlaying();
    }

    public void pausePlayer(){

        player.pause();
    }

    public void seek(int posn){

        player.seekTo(posn);
    }

    public void go(){

        player.start();
    }

    //skip to previous track
    public void playPrev(){
        songPosn--;
        if(songPosn<0) songPosn=songs.size()-1;
        playSong();
    }

    //skip to next
    public void playNext(){
        if(shuffle){
            int newSong = songPosn;
            while(newSong==songPosn){
                newSong=rand.nextInt(songs.size());
            }
            songPosn=newSong;
        }
        else{
            songPosn++;
            if(songPosn>=songs.size()) songPosn=0;
        }
        playSong();
    }

    public void onDestroy() {
        stopForeground(true);
    }

    //toggle shuffle
    public void setShuffle(){
        shuffle= !shuffle;
    }


}
```

En android studio no me marca nada, dice que estoy bien:

[image: Imagen de referencia de mi codigo]

No se en que libreria este obsoleta o que parte del codigo este mal internamente
ademas de que estuve revisando las librerias que importe desde el android studio y ninguna me aparece como que necesita ser actualizada o que es obsoleta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Los métodos deprecados son `setAudioStreamType()` y el constructor `Notification.Builder(this)`.

No sé por qué android studio no marca las advertencias pero tal vez sea porque estás usando Java que en android se puede considerar un deprecated language (mira la [documentación](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/first)). Si haces click derecho en el nombre del archivo y selececcionas `Convert Java File to Kotlin File`, podrás ver las advertencias correctamente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En los mensajes te dirá que método usar para reemplazarlos. Para el builder es el constructor de dos argumentos `Builder(Context context, String channelId)` y para `setAudioStreamType` el reemplazo es `setAudioAttributes(AudioAttributes attributes)`